# Updating HTML upon drop down choice and checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have a drop down list accompanied by some javascript & jquery which displays some text and a check box depending on the choice. If the checkbox is ticked then the HTML displayed will change again. Text & checkbox are being displayed however when checking the tick box html is then not changing.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="plan">
    <div class="plan-details1"></div>
    <div class="plan-name">
        <select id="myselect">
            <option value="0">Please Select Your Mobile Plan</option>
            <option value="1">Package 1</option>
            <option value="2">Package 2</option>
            <option value="3">Package 3</option>
            <option value="4">Package 4</option>
            <option value="5">Package 5</option>
            <option value="6">Package 6</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="plan-price"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('#myselect').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();

        if (val == '1') {
            $('.plan-details1').html('This Is Working 1<br/>');
            $('.plan-price').html('<div id="price-m">Price: &euro;18</div><input type="checkbox" id="handset-m" value="Car" onClick="validate()"> Handset');
        }

        if (val == '2') {
            $('.plan-details1').html('This Is Working 2<br/>');
            $('.plan-price').html('<div id="price-l">Price: &euro;25</div><input type="checkbox" id="handset-l" value="Car" onClick="validate()"> Handset');
        }

        if (val == '3') {
            $('.plan-details1').html('This Is Working 3<br/>');
        }

        if (val == '4') {
            $('.plan-details1').html('This Is Working 4<br/>');
        }

        if (val == '5') {
            $('.plan-details1').html('This Is Working 5<br/>');
        }

        if (val == '6') {
            $('.plan-details').html('This Is Working 6<br/>');
        }

    });
});

function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('handset-m').checked) {
            document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;20';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;18';
        }

        if (document.getElementById('handset-l').checked) {
            document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;35';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;25';
        }
    }
```

A fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4b6/

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Try declaring a variable for $('.plan-details1') outside of your change handler and using this variable instead of declaring a jquery object over and over each time the checkbox changes. You could do this for all of the jquery objects you are reusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not working because you insert the checkboxes as HTML markup. The `onclick` handlers is never attached to a real function. Change your code to this :

```
 if (val == '1') {
            $('.plan-details1').html('This Is Working 1<br/>');
            $('.plan-price').html('<div id="price-m">Price: &euro;18</div><input type="checkbox" id="handset-m" value="Car"> Handset');
            document.getElementById("handset-m").onclick = validate;
        }

        if (val == '2') {
            $('.plan-details1').html('This Is Working 2<br/>');
            $('.plan-price').html('<div id="price-l">Price: &euro;25</div><input type="checkbox" id="handset-l" value="Car"> Handset');
            document.getElementById("handset-l").onclick = validate;
        }
```

Now thew checkboxes is actually attached to the `validate()` function. BTW, change the validate function to check if the checkboxes exists / is inserted to avoid "*cannot set checked of null*" errors :

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('handset-m')) {
        if (document.getElementById('handset-m').checked) {
            document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;20';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;18';
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('handset-l')) {
        if (document.getElementById('handset-l').checked) {
            document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;35';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;25';
        }
    }
}
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8upk3/**

Comment: @user3025379 You are welcome! Sometimes you just need fresh eyes to the problem. Could have been there myself, never thinking about it was inserting of the markup that was the problem, but dozens of other things :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

validate is actually on the global scope, but the problem is with the validate function itself:
here is a fixed version:

```
function validate() {
    if(document.getElementById('handset-m')) {
        if (document.getElementById('handset-m').checked) {
            document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;20';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;18';
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('handset-l')) {
        if (document.getElementById('handset-l').checked) {
            document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;35';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;25';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however this is still not functioning. When I am trying to see the error from the log, this is what its being given:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null `

Comment: Also note that in the posted answer, you run the risk of binding multiple events to the click. If you change the validate to .click(function() {alert("hi")}) in the fiddle, select 1, click the thing, select something else, select 1 again, click the thing, the function runs twice.

Comment: validate **IS** in the global scope. What do you think it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Scope problem.

You can either try to put listeners on your checkboxes, or declare your function in your document.ready

```
validate = function() {
    if (document.getElementById('handset-m').checked) {
        document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;20';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('price-m').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;18';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('handset-l').checked) {
        document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;35';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('price-l').innerHTML = 'Price: &euro;25';
    }
};
```

I updated  [your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4b6/18/)

Note that your function is not really efficient, you should test the presence of your elements ('handset-m', ''handset-l'...) before testing if they are checked.

**EDIT**

Here's an other way to do it, with jQuery listeners :

```
$('#plan').on('click','#handset-m, #handset-l', function(){console.log('test');
   $this = $(this);
   id = this.id;
   var lbl = 'Price: &euro;';
   if(true === $this.prop('checked')){
       lbl += ('handset-m' === id) ? '20' : '35';
   }
   else {
       lbl += ('handset-m' === id) ? '18' : '25';
   }

   $this.prev('div').html(lbl);
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4b6/20/)